# How do I stop this iteration?

Tags: c#, onclick

```
   foreach(HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
    {
        if(element.GetAttribute("href") ==
            "http://myblog.com/Insert/Insertred.html")
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click");

        }

    }
```

---

How do I stop this `foreach` loop from iterating?
This loop is repeated frequently

Comment: When do you want to stop the loop?

Comment: When is it done? It will automatically stop after iterating over all the elements. But if you don't need to iterate over all elements you will want to stop it early. My question is: when? If you want it to stop as soon as it has invoked a single click, then Royi Namir's answer is correct. If you want it to stop after checking all elements, then you don't need to change anything. It already does just that.

Comment: Is this block of code within an event handler? If so, which?

Answer (score 2):

you should use [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("href") == "http://myblog.com/Insert/Insertred.html")
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;

                }

   }
```

or you can use `return` and it will exit the method itself.

Comment: break and return not work ?it means not stop this loop ?! i don't know why ?

Comment: please help , dosen't work?

Comment: @SepehrKalantarian I dont understand your question.

Comment: i use break and return but it cant stop this loop ?! how can i stop this loop ? i want to the program click this link "myblog.com/Insert/Insertred.html" when the program click this link for once ,don't click more ! I want to when the program click this loop , come out from this loop ?!

Answer (score 1):

By `break`ing out of the foreach loop.

```
        foreach (var foo in bar)
        {
            if (foo == null)
                break; // Stops iterating the foreach completely, and moves on to the next line of code after the loop.
        }
```

Comment: can u describe it ? or how can i use it on the main code(up)?